# How to get all the SIDs of the groups of a current user

Tags: windows, go

I need to get all the SIDs of the groups of a current user.

I noticed the [`os/user`](https://godoc.org/os/user) package may do this, but I cannot access the functions in [`lookup_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/os/user/lookup_windows.go), because the functions are not capitalized, right?

How can I get all the SIDs of the groups of the current user?

Comment: Since you have the source code of `lookup_windows.go` you might modify it. However, you probably should not. Looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What is your real issue? What do you want to do?

Comment: So, is this to be understood as an example of an implementation, or am I missing something in general?

Comment: I want to use the listGroups function.

Comment: If it is not a public function you cannot use it without rewriting it

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: @Flimzy: Beyond what I described above, I need to get all the SIDs of the groups of a current user. Thats on windows, powershell and cmd is not an option, so I Iooked into packages I might use.

Comment: Above you have not described your goal. You've described your failed attempts to reach your goal, without telling us what you're trying to do. This is what is meant by "XY Problem."  Now, finally, you have explained your actual goal, so we may now be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
user, err := user.Current()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
groupIds, err := user.GroupIds()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Groups: %v\n", groupIds)
```

Comment: @oldsport: Of course... user is correct. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use this package in my project, e.g. the listGoups

Not at all.

You simply cannot. You have to use a different package, e.g. your own fork.